# Dynamically Change ID of an HTML Element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list

Alright.
I have created a custom object that I am using to build a list of things. One of the functions for this custom object involves adding the object to a list. In this list, there is a value I assign to each different element that keeps track of how many of that item have been added to the list. Such as:

(3) Object#1
(2) Object#2

3 and 2 of course being the 'count' value of that object. My problem is that I am creating the list dynamically by calling:

```
function Thing(count, value)
{
    this.count=count;
    this.value=value;
}

Thing.prototype.addToList = function()
{
if (this.count == 0)
{
    this.count++;

    var list = document.getElementById("blah");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var interior = "<span id='counter'>("+this.count+")</span>";
    li.innerHTML = interior;
    list.appendChild(li);
}
else
{
    this.count++;
    var countInc = document.getElementById("counter");
    countInc.innerHTML = "("+this.count+")";
}
}
```

This works fine, but if I am to add multiple Objects with separate count values, there is no way to distinguish between them, and as a result, the first 'counter' span in the list is altered with the the count value of the most recently added object. All other count values remain the same (1). I have tried:

```
var interior = "<span id='counter"+this.value+"'>("+this.count+")</span>";
```

To try and create a unique id each time, but this isn't working. Basically, I am wondering how I can create new ID values each time I instantiate a new Object.

Comment: Are you using the `new` keyword? That should ensure that you have unique objects.

Comment: @arxanas yes, I instantiate them via:

    var object1 = new Thing (0, "blah");

Comment: the problem is that the id for counter span is the same for all different instances of the object, just need to know the correct way to change the id name for each different object so no two objects have the same id associated with their count value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var list = document.getElementById("blah");
var li = document.createElement("li");
var interior = "<span id='counter-"+this.count+"'>("+this.count+")</span>";
li.innerHTML = interior;
```

Comment: no, i want to change, the id of the span so its different for each instance of the Thing object.

Comment: yeah, nice, what the hell is the issue with what i was doing? All it took was a dash?

Comment: you were doing this.value and there is nothing like this.value

Comment: I literally did exactly what you have above except without the dash after counter, didn't work. Then I add the dash after counter and it works?? quirky